# Measuring traffic server-side for 50+domains

Tags: google-analytics, traffic-measurement

I have a web-server with 50+ domains hosted. I am trying to find a tool that would give me some stats on incoming traffic for those domains. I know I can install a separate Google analytics code into each of those but that's just too much work and the reporting would be tricky. I want to see all domains in a single report/dashboard. Whats' the best way to do this? I think I could use Google cross-domain tracking but I thought I'd ask here if any better alternatives around?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Google Analytics 360, the best solution is to track them separately and create an external dashboard (e.g. data studio) that collects information from the various Properties and displays it in one place.

If you track everything in Google Analytics Standard within the same Property, with all those domains and depending on the volume of traffic, the risk of seeing sampled data in non-standard reports is almost insured.